# Split dataframe at boolean

Tags: pandas, split, boolean

[image]

How can I split this dataframe at all True in Monthdiff such that I get a seperate dataframe for rows 0:2, rows 3:4, rows 5:6 etc..

Regards,

Dante

Comment: I've already found it: df_split = np.split(dt, *np.where(dt.Monthdiff == True))

Comment: Nooo, I didn't see the comment :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and a list comprehension with [`df['Monthdiff'].cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) as grouper:

```
dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby(df['Monthdiff'].cumsum())]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code, but hope it can help you:

```
indices = df[df['bool'] == True].index 
ind0 = indices[0]
dfs = [df.iloc[:ind0,:]]

for ind in indices[1:]:
    dfs.append(df.iloc[ind0:ind])
    ind0 = ind

dfs.append(df.iloc[ind0:,:])
```